# Firestore field update throws error 'read properties undefined' when deployed on production server

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting below error on document update. This works fine when I run the flutter web application on local i.e. flutter run. however getting below error when release version deployed on production server.

Please help!

Update Query:
db.collection("users").doc("1234").update({"token": null});

Error:
main.dart.js:4575 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question lacks diagnostically useful information.

Answer (score 0):

**After many trials and runs found another way to update document fields.**

Updated Query as below:

```
db.collection("users").doc("1234").set({"token": null},
        SetOptions(merge: true, mergeFields: List<String>.of(["token"])));
```

Hope the solution is useful.